# Measure or calculated column based on values from another table

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-modeling, powerbi-desktop

I have the model below and I want to calculate the capacity of each assignee based on the remaining days in a Sprint.

This would be basically **Users[USER_DAILY_CAPACITY] * SPRINTS[DAYS_REMAINING_IN_SPRINT]** but I can't achieve this in DAX.

[Data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZhR9.png)

Ultimately I want to display the Original Effort vs Remaining effort vs Remaining capacity per assignee and filter with Sprints_Reports.SPRINT_ID .

I tried merging USER with SPRINTS using some intermediary tables and I can calculate the Remaining capacity per user, but with no direct relationship between SPRINTS and ISSUES doesn't bring the correct data if I filter with the Sprints_Reports.SPRINT_ID .

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The issue is complicated enough. Not sure that it can be an answer just looking through you model and reading question.  If you add some dummy data table  and dummy results, or share with your .pbix , then it's a chance to get the answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.